# Can't get actual Checked Items from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm having a problem getting the Checked Items on my listview.
The thing is that No matter what when i call the getCheckedItemsCount() o getCheckedItemPositions() it always returns 1. No matter if there's 0 or 2 or more items checked.

This is my MainActivity, which implements MultiChoiceModeListener, to listen for when an item is checked. 
I do this because i check the items dynamically on the ListAdapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements MultiChoiceModeListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate (bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        setContentView (R.layout.main);

        this.getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        this.getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);

        _dataAdapter = new ServerListAdapter (this);
        this.getListView(). setAdapter(_dataAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu (this.getListView());
    }

    // This is called when i set the item as checked using setItemChecked on my ListAdapter.
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean isChecked) {


        SparseBooleanArray checke = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
        // This always returns 1. No matter If I have 0 or 2 items checked.
        int checkedCount = checkedItemPositions.size();

        // I Have also tried with getCheckedItemsCount() and it returns 1 too.

        if (checkedCount > 0)
        {
            // DO SOMETHING...
        }
        else
        {
                // DO SOME OTHER STUFF...
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for my ListAdapter. Only relevant code is here:

```
public class ServerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView (final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ListView listView = (ListView)parent;
        boolean isChecked = listView.isItemChecked(position);

        ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chkItemServerSelected)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {   


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton pCompound, boolean arg1) 
            {

                boolean isChecked = listView.isItemChecked(position);
                // Here i set the item as checked, o unchecked. This works ok.
                listView.setItemChecked(position, !isChecked);
            }

        });

        //Finally return the view
        return view;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

After looking around, i found out that the problem was that I was doing it the wrong way.

On my list adapter, on the onCheckedChanged, instead of using the current value get from the list view, I had to use the value from the checkbox, (since that's what I'm trying to achieve).

Previous code:

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, !isChecked);
```

New code:

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, pCompound.isChecked());
```

The thing is that this brought a new problem.
When the checked value IsChecked is **TRUE**, the event onItemCheckedStateChanged is raised, but when the value is **FALSE** it doesn't... any clues?

Comment: What row layout are you using? It doesn't look it implements Checkable...

Comment: @Sam I found the problem, but this brought a new problem. Please, take a look at the edited post. I am using a custom layout in which I included a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the ListView instance was getting all messed up so instead of using the checked value of the item listview, i used the ckeched value of the CheckBox control.

This change was made on the ListAdapter on the onCheckedChanged method of the checkbox:

Previous code:

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, !isChecked);
```

New code:

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, pCompound.isChecked());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a few overrides in your base adapter. I think you need to implement something like this: (in addition to getView)

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return myarray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return myarray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return myarray.get(position).getId();
    }
```

Comment: I found the problem, but this brought a new one. Please, take a look at the edited post.

I have implemented those overrides, but I just placed the relevant code, since the problem is not with the adapter itself.